# How do I extend a class inside of a folder in the same package in NetbBeans IDE 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I've created a default package `xyz` and within this package I have created a folder `x` so now there is a package by the name of `xyz.x`. Now in the main file of the regular package `xyz` I am trying to make it extend a class located inside of that folder `xyz.x`.

How do I do this? and How do I import that folder? I've already went to the Project properties, then libraries and under compiler, added a folder path to the folder I've just created.

Comment: `import xyz.x.SomeClass;` or `import xyz.x.*;` Hi & Welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created a project netbeans just use the project path to reach your desired Class:
[image]

```
package javaapplication5.xyz;

import javaapplication5.xyz.x.InsideX;

public class InsideXYZ extends InsideX {

}
```